# Rewriting paths for bazel

Tags: hooks, find-file, c

The Bazel build tool has some features that interact poorly with emacs. When you build a C/C++ project for sandboxing purposes it makes a crazy hierarchy of symlinks, and uses them when invoking GCC. This means when using compilation-mode if you jump to error you end up opening a file with a path like:

```
/home/${USER}/.cache/bazel/_bazel_${USER}/72672b89e7690222ab9003283b4ed26f/execroot/__main__/src/your_actual_file.cpp
```

Meanwhile the actual path is `/home/$USER/mycheckout/src/your_actual_file.cpp`. `__main__` is a directory of symlinks that mirror the subdirectories of the root of the real checkout (why there isn't just one symlink pointing to the root I don't know, that would be sane). This means that even with the long path `your_actual_file.cpp` is not a symlink, so simply asking emacs to follow symlinks doesn't fix it.

I'd like to redirect all files opened with the long form to the real checkout. I believe this will involve looking up the directory hierarchy until reaching main, then checking where the `src` symlink is pointing. But I'm not sure at what layer to hook into emacs -- how do I reliably change what file is actually opened anytime any emacs component tries to open a file? Also helpful if anybody else has already solved exactly this :)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew ah sorry my mistake

Comment: No problem. Thx.